# Using Python FTP Server (pyftplib) - create HTML file on log in

Tags: python, html, ftp, ftplib

I have a FTP server working great using Python and the pyftplib library (https://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/). I would like to, on login (either anonymous or user), create a html file reflecting the latest state of the server in a nice looking way. For example, all the files that are on the server and their properties nicely separated and looking nice. I thought that since I was already doing everything in Python, and my html wouldn't be overly complex, I would just have python write the html file on log in, and then the user could open the html file for the information that was written seconds before.

My main problem is that when I override the "public callbacks" section of the handlers.py (or any section so far), no file is created that I can find. I am new to python, but it seems like a modification in the handlers.py file should affect the Handler class. Another idea I plan on trying is to override the handler base class with my "on_login" function that does create the html file.

What I am really asking for is 
1) Advice from anybody who has done/tried this before
2) Any red flags that are going off in your head regarding my plan
3) Any other ideas (ideally strictly using python)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to start with writing "XXX" in the methods that you wrote and don't have any effect.  Then you'll know if the methods are called or not, at least :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was not editing the handler.py file, but rather creating my own subclass (myFTPHandler) and then redefining the onconnect method to write my html file then.

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Since you fixed your own problem you should mark this as the accepted answer so people know it's resolved.

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours :) 51 min left